# How to save created file to the user specified filepath in Java?

Tags: java, file, javafx, itext

This might be common question, but I didn't found exact solution.
I have a JavaFX application which creates PDF file (using iText 7) using data from cloud sql server.
However, this file is now saved in my specified file path.
I want my user to specify where he/she wants to save that file.

```
String dest = "itextData//singleLR.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
```

Now here, the path `dest` is already specified. I want it to be specified by user.

```
Expected output
//File browsing code on button click
//Got String in variable user_specified_path

String dest = user_specified_path;
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
```

Comment: Use a [FileChooser](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html).

Comment: @VGR Will this work for both Windows and Linux environments?

Comment: `FileChooser` is part of JavaFX. Of-course it will work on both Windows and linux platforms. The equivalent _Swing_ class is [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @VGR , I used JavaFX FileChooser.
However, instead of `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(scene)` , I used `fileChooser.showSaveDialog(scene);`

`showOpenDialog()` is used to open existing file.
`showSaveDialog()` is used to create new file

So my code goes like below,

```
print.setOnAction(event -> {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Save PDF File");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF File", "*.pdf"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(print.getScene().getWindow());
        if (selectedFile != null) {
           String dest = selectedfile.getAbsolutePath();
           PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
           PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
           Document document = new Document(pdf);
           //DOCUMENT WRITING CODE BEGINS
         }
}
```

For reference -> [Saving File with FileChooser in JavaFX](https://www.genuinecoder.com/save-files-javafx-filechooser/)